# Protect specific resources id with OAuth2 on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth

I have a working OAUTH2 implementation on Spring Boot, with AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer on the same implementation, using password grant.
About the server:

- The TokenStore is custom and uses a WebService to store the token remotely.
- I have a custom AuthenticationProvider.

This works for controlling access to resources based on given authorities, for instance, in the ResourceServer config:

```
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/resource/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    }
```

Now, I need to control that USER can access to "/api/resource/1" but not "/api/resource/2", this IDs can change and I fetch the list during the authentication.

I've tried to add the ID's list to OAuth2AccessToken additional information and adding a custom filter in the ResourceServer configuration but it always comes empty.

So, How's the proper way for implementing this without using JWT?

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and research, If someone is trying to achieve something similar, this is what I'll do:

- Map the allowed ID's to authorities, e.g. ID_201 and the modules as roles, so I will have a ROLE_ADMIN.
- It's possible to refer to path variables in Web Security Expressions, as explained in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-path-variables). So the idea is to pass the variable (resource id) and check whether it's allowed or not.

  ```
  public class WebSecurity {
     public boolean checkResourceId(Authentication authentication, int id) {
          //check if the list of authorities contains ID_{id}.
     }
  }
  ```

  And in the Web Security config:

  ```
  http
  .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/resource/{resourceId}/**").access("@webSecurity.checkResourceId(authentication,#resourceId)")
          ...
  ```

If you're working on Spring Boot with spring-security 4.0.4 be sure to upgrade to 4.1.1 as reported in this [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3781).